# ASP.NET MVC. How to submit form automatically when user leaves the page but still keep data validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, validation, onbeforeunload

I have a multi-controller, multi-page ASP.NET MVC application. On each "Edit" view, I'd like the form to be submitted when the user leaves the page, e.g. clicks on a link to another page, if the data has been modified.

I have achieved this using a "changed" flag, set on keypress, etc. and by handling the window.onbeforeunload event where I use JQuery to submit the form - $("#form").submit();

This all works, but if a user enters invalid data they don't see the original view with the validation messages, etc. but are taken to the next page anyway. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

The logic on leaving the page would be:

- Has the data been modified. If not then just go to the destination.
- If the data has been modified, submit the form.
- If the data is valid, go to the destination of the link they clicked.
- If the data isn't valid, stay on the same view with validation errors
  displayed.

I'm not sure it can be done. Would it help if the form data was submitted using an AJAX call?

Thanks in advance.

Doug

Comment: You need to check `if ($('form').Valid())` and if its not, cancel the submit. But do you really want to do this. If the user made a change then realized it was a mistake, then navigated away, you implementation would save the change without the user even knowing (and the saved data would not be wrong). At the very least you should have a confirm dialog.

Comment: Hi Stephen. Thanks for the comments. Am I correct in thinking that $('form').Valid() would just do client side validation? We have some heavyweight validation that can only be done server side, so I'm always going to need to submit the form to get the full validation.

I understand your comments about the danger of accidentally saving, but for this application it would be OK. Your suggestion of a notification is good though.

Comment: Yes, it will only do server side validation. If you also wanted to implement separate server side validation, then you going to need to first submit the data using ajax and return a result with the errors (and cancel the navigation is so)